# How to put "<span>" tag value into the "input" value

Tags: mysql

how can I put span tag value to the "input value" as below:

```
<input id="example_input" value="HERE IS I WANT SPAN TAG VALUE COME" > </input>

<span id="example_span"> </span>

<button type="submit" id="button">SAVE</button></td>
```

When I push the save button than span tag value will be goes to input tag value..

how can I do that?

maybe you can think like that :

```
<input id="example_input" value="<span id="example_span"> </span>" >
</input>
```

Comment: In your getData1 function, what is the html element with the id of travers_tutucu_sayisi?  A span or an input?  If it is a span, then the span's innerHTML will get the value assigned to it.  If an input, then the innerHTML isn't the same as an input's value.  To set an input's value you can use the jQuery .val( ... ) function, similar to what you're doing in the jQuery click event handler function, except you put a value in between the parentheses.  When you run the above code using your browser's code inspector without the jQuery part, does your element get the right value/content?

Comment: More important, the getData1 function is called using the button's onclick AND you also use jQuery to assign a click  handler to the same button, it is better if you move the getData1 call into the button click handler function, before where the handler function tries to get the form(?) values it posts.

Comment: this is not all of my code.. I copy paste part of my codes to understand what I am trying to do...I changed travers_tutucu to direk_olcusu...

Comment: everything works in my code with "input tag"  parameters but when I call "span tag" parameter with api.scene than I cant send it to mysql database

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem like that:

```
<input type="text" id="deneme" value=""><span  style="display:block;" id="ray_olcusu"> 

<td  colspan="12">    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block"  onclick="getData1();">
    İMALAT ÖLÇÜLERİNİ ÇIKART

  </button></td>

<script>

function getData1() { var res = api.scene.getData({name: 'ray_olcusu'});

document.getElementById('ray_olcusu').innerHTML=res.data[0].data

document.getElementById("deneme").value = document.getElementById("ray_olcusu").textContent;

} </script>
```

Comment: with that way: I put span tag value into the input tag value...

Comment: I get value to span tag from api.scene.getData and put it into "input" tag and than so I can send it to mysql database.